# Getting MongooseServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: xxx.xx.xx.xx is not in the cert's list:

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created self signed certificate in my linux machine where i have given certificate CN same as IP of that linux
I have added them in mongodb.conf and restarted the server
i am able to connecte via command

**mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodbcerts/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/mongodbcerts/ca.pem**

But when i am trying to connect from nodeJS mongoose i am getting error like

**MongooseServerSelectionError: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: XXX.xx.x.xx is not in the cert's list:**

My nodejs code for connecting mongodb   as follows

```
const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true,
     useNewUrlParser: true, 
     useUnifiedTopology: true,
     useFindAndModify: false ,
     server:{
    ssl: true,
    sslValidate:true,
    sslCA: require('fs').readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongodbcerts/ca.pem"),
    sslKey:require('fs').readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongodbcerts/mongodb.key"),
    sslCert:require('fs').readFileSync("/etc/ssl/mongodbcerts/mongodb.crt")
            }
};

let mongo_url="mongodb://username:password@IPaddress/DB"
console.log(mongo_url)
mongoose.connect(mongo_url,connectionOptions).then(() => console.log( 'Database Connected' ))
.catch(err => console.log( err ));;
```

Please let me know the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake i did was I have created self signed certificate with Common Name(CN) as IP address (XXX.xx.x.xx) but we need to create the self signed certificates with CN as hostname.
To get the hostname open mongo shell and execute below command:

```
>getHostName()
```

You will hostname of that VM and create self signed certificates with same host name and try connect with mongoose nodejs. It will work.
Support Doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67690502/10586889) recently. Starting in MongoDB 4.2, when performing comparison of SAN, MongoDB supports comparison of IP addresses as well. You can use IP address in the CN field but make sure your openssl configuration file contains your servers IP address in the **alt_names** section.

Here's a sample cnf file provided in the official MongoDB docs -

```
# NOT FOR PRODUCTION USE. OpenSSL configuration file for testing.


[ req ]
default_bits = 4096
default_keyfile = myTestServerCertificateKey.pem    ## The default private key file name.
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = req_dn
req_extensions = v3_req

[ v3_req ]
subjectKeyIdentifier  = hash
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
nsComment = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate for TESTING only.  NOT FOR PRODUCTION USE."
extendedKeyUsage  = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 =         ##TODO: Enter the DNS names if using hostname, otherwise remove this line
IP.1 =          ##TODO: Enter the IP address if using IP address

[ req_dn ]
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = TestServerCertificateCountry
countryName_min = 2
countryName_max = 2

stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = TestServerCertificateState
stateOrProvinceName_max = 64

localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = TestServerCertificateLocality
localityName_max = 64

organizationName = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default = TestServerCertificateOrg
organizationName_max = 64

organizationalUnitName = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default = TestServerCertificateOrgUnit
organizationalUnitName_max = 64

commonName = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_max = 64
```