# Connecting pymongo client to mongodb server with TLS

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have 2 instances on Google Cloud :

**Instance A** and **Instance B** - Both have a static external IP address.

**Instance A** running the community edition of the MongoDB server v4.4.6.

- I have generated self-signed certificates to enable TLS
- I have set the firewall rules in my cloud network to allow traffic to the MongoDB port from **Instance B**s IP address

As such, I am successfully able to use the mongo shell(v4.4.6) in **Instance B** to connect to the mongo server running on **Instance A**. This is the command that I use -

```
mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile client.pem --tlsCAFile ca.pem <instance_a_ip>:<port>/admin -u <userName> -p
```

I would like to use the pymongo(v3.11.4) client from **Instance B** in order to connect to my MongoDB server in **Instance A** and I have tried that using this in an interactive python shell -

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://<instance_a_ip>:<port>/admin", tls=True, tlsCertificateKeyFile='./client.pem', tlsCAFile='./ca.pem', username='<userName>', password='<userPassword>')
```

However, I am not able to connect and this is the error that I receive -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1319, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1207, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1100, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1816, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1802, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 496, in get_server_session
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/home/varun/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: <instance_a_ip>:<port>: ("Invalid DNS pattern b'127.0.0.1'.",), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 60ad03827b267af40c2edf4b, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('<instance_a_ip>', <port>) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('<instance_a_ip>:<port>: ("Invalid DNS pattern b\'127.0.0.1\'.",)')>]>
```

I am new to MongoDB and not able to figure out how to go about this, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What in your setup resolves to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I am not 100% sure either, because when I use the mongo shell I am able to connect to the mongo server well. I am suspecting this has something to do with pymongo?

Comment: You can patch the driver to reraise the exception where AutoReconnect is handled, this will give you the stack trace for the original problem.

Comment: Managed to solve the problem by installing the Nodejs client for mongodb. It provided me with a much better exception that I could trace back to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Debugged the issue by installing the Nodejs client for MongoDB. The Node client provided a much better message upon failure -

```
[Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 34.126.133.72 is not in the cert's list
```

Thanks to the meaningful error, I read through the OpenSSL configuration file that I had used while creating the self-signed certificates. Rectified the error I made in the config file as such -

**Original config file which caused the error**

```
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = 127.0.0.1
DNS.2 = <instance_a_ip>
```

**Rectified config file which now works with all MongoDB clients**

```
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = <instance_a_ip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate is self-signed, add this option when create MongoClient.

```py
tlsInsecure=True
```

code will be like this

```py
client = MongoClient(
    ["<instance_a_ip>:<port>"], 
    tls=True, 
    tlsInsecure=True, 
    tlsCertificateKeyFile='./client.pem', 
    tlsCAFile='./ca.pem', 
    username='<userName>', 
    password='<userPassword>'
)
```